# Distance between geography points return each TOP 1

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have two sql server 2016 tables:
Customers which has about 200k rows
Shops which has 100 rows

Both tables contain a geography field.

For each customer I need to find their closest shop.

I have created the code below which gives the correct results but returns the distance between every shop and customer and I only need TOP 1 for each customer. I could create a ROW_NUMBER and then =1 but I'm worried about the amount of data this will create in the cte and how long it will take to run.

```
select t1.[CustNo_],t1.Latitude, t1.Longitude,t1.GeoLoc
      ,t2.[ShopCode]
      ,t1.GeoLoc.STDistance(t2.GeoLoc)/1000 as DistanceApartKM
from #Customers t1
join #Shops t2
on (t1.GeoLoc.STDistance(t2.GeoLoc) <= 10000)
order by t1.[CustNo_], DistanceApartKM
```

I am now going to try suggestion to use Cross Apply, amended code below.

```
select t1.[CustNo_],t1.Latitude, t1.Longitude,t1.GeoLoc
      ,x.[ShopCode]
      ,x.DistanceApartKM
from #Customers t1
cross apply (select top 1 t2.[ShopCode]
            ,t1.GeoLoc.STDistance(t2.GeoLoc)/1000 as DistanceApartKM
             from #Shops t2
             where (t1.GeoLoc.STDistance(t2.GeoLoc) <= 10000)
         order by DistanceApartKM
        ) x
 order by t1.[CustNo_]
```

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=cff380e216eaad6153c0d0fa828e3ac7

Comment: Customer 104449 should only return ShopCode 4
Customer 1056 should only return ShopCode 4
etc.

Comment: `CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP(1) .. ORDER BY ...)`. It'll take as long as the `ORDER BY` needs to run; SQL Server supports such things as spatial indexes, but I have no experience with that.

Comment: Ah yes good idea Jeroen I'll try a Cross Apply with top 1